# Center absolutely positioned child element

Tags: html, css

I need to horizontally center the child element of an inline block. The issue is that the child sub menu is variable width and can be wider than its parent. My initial solution was to set the child element a left & right of -50px but this is not really a variable width and instead statically sets it to be 100px wider than its parent.

```css
.main-menu {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0px;
    font-size: 0rem;
}
.main-menu li {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    line-height: 1em;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    padding: 0 25px;
    position: relative;
}
li > a {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    padding: 21px 0 19px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #282828;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out, background-image 0s, background-position 0s;
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out, background-image 0s, background-position 0s;
}
.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: -50px;
    right: -50px;
    max-width: 250px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    min-width: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 17px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #dcdcdc inset;
    border-top: 18px solid #ffdd00;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu clearfix"><li id="menu-item-657" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children first menu-item-657">
<li id="menu-item-657" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children first menu-item-657"><a href="link">Solutions</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-220469" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-220469"><a href="link">Solutions</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-18009" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18009"><a href="link">How It Works</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-10344" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10344"><a href="link">Why Use It</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-3375" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3375"><a href="link">Products</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: `text-align: center` instead of `left` for `sub-menu` works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I usually do in this kind of situation:

```css
.parent {
    /*....your existing css...*/
    position: relative;
}
.sub-menu {
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sub-menu">
    Centered
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, worked a treat :) thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem last week and something like this fixed my issue:

```
li > a {
    ....your existing css...
    position: relative;
}
.sub-menu {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -100%;
    margin-right: -100%;
}
```

In my case, `.sub-menu` was wider than `li > a`, but I wanted `.sub-menu` to be centered underneath `li > a`. Is that the issue you're having?

Comment: Hey - thanks for taking the time to answer, yeah it is the problem I'm having but unfortunately the above wont work, this is because the bottom menu isn't really dynamic width but still based on its parent and with some of the smaller sub menus ends up too wide :(